# Php загрузка данных в бд в формате json

Tags: php, база-данных

Есть форма для добавление поста в бд, тут все понятно все работает.Надо еще сделать кнопку для загрузки поста в формате JSON.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: json_encode / json_decode

Comment: Эти я функции знаю. Просто кодировать перед отправкой в бд?

Comment: Да, json_encode превращает объект или массив в строку.

Comment: с формы принимать поля и каждое кодировать в json?

Comment: Я не могу знать, потому что вопрос задан слишком размыто. И что подраумевается под загрузкой поста в json - не понятно. Почитайте про json, посмотрите примеры данных в этом формате и все станет понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Делаете кнопку и привязываете к ней action. В обработчике пишите запрос в БД, а далее воспользуйтесь функцией json_encode();
Мануал прилагается: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php